# Getting content from Google News

Tags: php

Can I get text from news.google.com? When I view code, I see that it's JavaScript, so I can't get the text on the page. Can anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try the RSS feeds. See:

http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255

Comment: RSS is definitely the way to go.  I recommend SimplePie for reading RSS in PHP.

Comment: thank you for answer but i need to get top search of news ex. http://news.google.co.th  please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `&output=rss` to the end of many Google News URLs allows you to get the results in an XML/RSS format instead of as a mix of JavaScript and HTML.

For example, http://news.google.co.th/news/search?&q=facebook&output=rss.

PHP has a variety of XML libraries that could be used to parse the content, but I am not familiar enough with them to produce example code.